# Visual Basic LESS THAN Issue?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, if-statement, operators

I am trying to work with decimals

```
If "3.04" < "12.4" Then
    finalPrice = "perfect"
Else
    finalPrice = "too big"

End If
```

So 3.04 is not bigger than 12.4 right? When I run this it's thinking 3.04 IS bigger than 12.4. Why is it doing that? It should return `perfect` instead of returning `too big` which is what it's currently doing.

Is it a decimal issue?

Comment: using that approach, see what `"1" + "2"` results in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare strings in that way (which is what it is, being encased in quotes). As this is a string comparison, lexicographically, "3" (the leftmost character) is higher than "1". Try parsing the numbers into a floating point number, then your comparison will work.

Additionally, remember, parse safely! If the parse fails, prepare to have some defensive coding around it. If anything, avoid this floating point number being entered in string form at all if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, something so simple. Don't worry, the string used in that is not from the user.